# Getting all file names at a given folder name

Tags: file, matlab, directory

How can I get the names of files in a given folder name at Matlab?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use the [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) function. Like so:

```
allFiles = dir( 'c:\my\folder' );
allNames = { allFiles.name };
```

Comment: For only files (not folders), modify the second line to `{allFiles(arrayfun(@(x) ~x.isdir, allFiles)).name}`.

Comment: @Richie: It's even easier than that: `{allFiles(~[allFiles.isdir]).name}`

Answer (score -1):

If you're on linux you can call the `find` command and process the output. `find` allows for much more advanced features than just using `dir`, and can be called using `system('find path')`.

Comment: Dear down-voter: I would be very grateful if you would leave some feedback as to why this was not a useful answer. Thanks!