# assigning .xls files in folder to individual names matlab

Tags: matlab, assign

I want to create a script i Matlab where all the individual objects are linked to a variable.

It would look like this:

```
M1 = xlsread('BonBon.xls');
M2 = xlsread('Bornfyn.xls');
```

Thing is i have about 300 .xls files i have to assign.

Is there a way of telling Matlab to get all the individual files in a specific folder (/subfolder) and assign them to a name? (Mx)

I have tried to use dir function but i cannot solve how i should define the folders.
[Getting all file names at a given folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803915/getting-all-file-names-at-a-given-folder-name)

thereby i have tried http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/273916
But that is even more complicated to figure out how i should costumize that script. (besides adding .xls to the list of filetypes).

Sincerely

Comment: What do you mean "i cannot solve how i should define the folders"? What OS are you using?

Comment: i am using osx so i have defined it from /, from /MATLAB and /Maend(which is the folder i have my files in)

Comment: I cannot read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803915/getting-all-file-names-at-a-given-folder-name should be the script i was looking for. As far it does not define the names to the variables, only getting the files and getting the names of the files.

Comment: I suspect (I'm not that familiar with OSX) that you should have a folder like `/home/my/data/here`. What is the output when you type `pwd` on the MATLAB command line? Once you have the names of the files, you can write a loop, something like `for ii = 1:len(names) M(ii) = xlsread(names(i)); end`

Comment: 'names' is then replaces with alle the names in the folder i guess, commaseparated?  (BorBor.xls,BorKBH.xls...) and xlsread(BorBor.xls,BorKBH.xls...(i);

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is... `names` is itself a variable that stores all the file names. If you follow the instructions in the linked question, you will have a variable called `allNames`. Each row of `allNames` contains a different file name. When you write a `for` loop like I wrote above, you are telling the computer to go through the variable `ii` one by one. Then it looks at the `ii`th row of `allNames` and tells `xlsread` to use that filename, and it assigns the result to the `ii`th row of `M`. Does that help?

Comment: Matlab tells me that there is an error with len in: `for ii = 1:len(allNames) M(ii) = xlsread(names(1i)); 
end`
 Hence: "Undefined function 'len' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

Otherwise you were absolutely right about the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803915/getting-all-file-names-at-a-given-folder-name -code influence in the total and overall code.

Comment: I have tested so far and gotten this result: `allFiles = dir( '*.xls' );
allNames = { allFiles.name };

for ii = 1:length(allNames) M(ii) = xlsread(allFiles(ii)); 
end`

but Matlab tells me that allFiles must be a string.

Comment: It works now. defining `allFiles = dir( '*.xls''String' );` as a string in `'String'` makes it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry about the mixup with `len`... I'm used to Python :-)