# I can't get the dir command to work in Matlab to work and return the folder names in a parent folder

Tags: matlab

I've looked for help and every solution I get seems to revolve around this command

```
allFiles = dir('/labs/srslab/data_main/ect');
```

Everytime I do this I get an array of 222 variable with each row saying the same thing: `<1x1 struct>`.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm very new to MATLAB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all file names at a given folder name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803915/getting-all-file-names-at-a-given-folder-name)

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. The return value of `dir` is a [`struct`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), which (among others) has a `name` field containing the file or folder name.

Comment: It's fine. Which Matlab version do you have? I think that if you double click on this `<1x1 struct>`, you will see the details. In newer versions, data is displayed all together.

Comment: @hbaderts Thank you so much